# Read android URL from External file

Tags: android, xml

I'm a new android developer. 
I made a live streaming app that reads the URL,Station Name and Station Description from the resource file. I works fine. 
But if whenever i need to add new channel i must update the *string resources* file and recompile the application. Is there any way to update the channel list and URL that is hosted on any other hosting sites or server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,you can't change strings.xml dynamically since it's a compiled resource. There are other mechanisms for saving data in Android, here's a nice post that covers this topic: [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Hope this helps.